# iOS Authenticate Azure Active Directory & get calendar events from office 365 exchange

Tags: ios, azure, exchangewebservices, azure-mobile-services

Trying to Authenticate with Azure Active Directory and fetch mail, calendar data, accessToken is returned successfully:

```
authority = @"https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";
redirectUriString = @"http://xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/oauth";
resourceId = @"https://outlook.office365.com";
clientId = @"xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxx";

-(void) getToken : (BOOL) clearCache completionHandler:(void (^) (NSString*))completionBlock;
{
ADAuthenticationError *error;
authContext = [ADAuthenticationContext authenticationContextWithAuthority:authority
                                                                    error:&error];
[authContext setValidateAuthority:YES];

NSURL *redirectUri = [NSURL URLWithString:redirectUriString];

if(clearCache){
    [authContext.tokenCacheStore removeAllWithError:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}


[authContext acquireTokenWithResource:resourceId
                             clientId:clientId
                          redirectUri:redirectUri
                      completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) {
                          if (AD_SUCCEEDED != result.status){
                              // display error on the screen
                              [self showError:result.error.errorDetails];
                          }
                          else{
                              completionBlock(result.accessToken);
                          }
                      }];
```

}

-(NSArray*)getEventsList
{

```
__block NSMutableArray * todoList;

[self getToken:YES completionHandler:^(NSString* accessToken){

    NSURL *todoRestApiURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/inbox/messages?$top=2"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:todoRestApiURL];

    NSString *authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", @""];

    [request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request addValue:@"application/json; odata.metadata=none" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept"];


    [request addValue:@"fbbadfe-9211-1234-9654-fe435986a1d6" forHTTPHeaderField:@"client-request-id"];

    [request addValue:@"Presence-Propelics/1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    //[request addValue:@"true" forHTTPHeaderField:@"return-client-request-id"];



    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if (error == nil){

            NSArray *scenarios = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            todoList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:scenarios];

            //each object is a key value pair
            NSDictionary *keyVauePairs;

            for(int i =0; i < todoList.count; i++)
            {
                keyVauePairs = [todoList objectAtIndex:i];

                NSLog(@"%@", keyVauePairs);

            }

        }
        NSLog(@"Finished");
        //[delegate updateTodoList:TodoList];

    }];

}];
return nil; }
```

Error is returned in response object:

{
    error =     {
        code = ErrorAccessDenied;
        message = "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.";
    };
}

Answer (score 1):

I know its late to answer this but it might be helpful for someone like me who was struggling to get the same thing done

I have done this using the [office 365 SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-iOS) for iOS which has all the inbuilt classes to do your work.

If you download their sample code it will provide you all the details you require to do certain operations (mail, calendar, contacts, one drive).

Before using the SDK make sure you login to Azure AD and [register your application and add permissions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2014/10/06/developing-ios-apps-with-azure-and-office-365-apis.aspx) so that you do not get 403 error code or any access denied message.

I am using the below code to fetch my events details from outlook calendar

```
    [self getClientEvents:^(MSOutlookClient *client) {
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[[client getMe] getEvents] read:^(NSArray<MSOutlookEvent> *events, MSODataException *error) {

            if (error==nil) {
                if (events.count!=0) {

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        for(MSOutlookEvent *calendarEvent in events){
                            NSLog(@"name = %@",calendarEvent.Subject);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"No events found for today");
                }
            }
        }];
        [task resume];
    }];
```

**getClientEvents** is a method which gives call to the Office 365 SDK and fetches the event details of the user but it first fetches the token for the resource and then makes the call with the acquired token

```
-(void)getClientEvents : (void (^) (MSOutlookClient* ))callback{

[self getTokenWith : @"https://outlook.office365.com" :true completionHandler:^(NSString *token) {

    MSODataDefaultDependencyResolver* resolver = [MSODataDefaultDependencyResolver alloc];
    MSODataOAuthCredentials* credentials = [MSODataOAuthCredentials alloc];
    [credentials addToken:token];

    MSODataCredentialsImpl* credentialsImpl = [MSODataCredentialsImpl alloc];

    [credentialsImpl setCredentials:credentials];
    [resolver setCredentialsFactory:credentialsImpl];
    [[resolver getLogger] log:@"Going to call client API" :(MSODataLogLevel *)INFO];

    callback([[MSOutlookClient alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0" dependencyResolver:resolver]);
}];
}
```

**getTokenWith method** fetches the token for a resource first and then with the acquired token makes the necessary calls to fetch the events, but before fetching the token it checks in the cache to see if there are any tokens available for the same resource.

```
// fetch tokens for resources
- (void) getTokenWith :(NSString *)resourceId : (BOOL) clearCache completionHandler:(void (^) (NSString *))completionBlock;
{
// first check if the token for the resource is present or not
if([self getCacheToken : resourceId completionHandler:completionBlock]) return;

ADAuthenticationError *error;
authContext = [ADAuthenticationContext authenticationContextWithAuthority:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authority"] error:&error];

NSURL *redirectUri = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_REDIRECT_URI"];

[authContext acquireTokenWithResource:resourceId
                             clientId:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"clientID"]
                          redirectUri:redirectUri
                      completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult  *result) {

                          if (AD_SUCCEEDED != result.status){
                              [self showError:result.error.errorDetails];
                          }
                          else{
                              NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                              [userDefaults setObject:result.tokenCacheStoreItem.userInformation.userId forKey:@"LogInUser"];
                              [userDefaults synchronize];

                              completionBlock(result.accessToken);
                          }
                      }];
}
```

**getCacheToken method:** Checks if there are any reusable token for any resources.

```
-(BOOL)getCacheToken : (NSString *)resourceId  completionHandler:(void (^) (NSString *))completionBlock {
ADAuthenticationError * error;
id<ADTokenCacheStoring> cache = [ADAuthenticationSettings sharedInstance].defaultTokenCacheStore;
NSArray *array = [cache allItemsWithError:&error];

if([array count] == 0) return false;
ADTokenCacheStoreItem *cacheItem;

for (ADTokenCacheStoreItem *item in array) {
    if([item.resource isEqualToString:resourceId]){
        cacheItem = item;
        break;
    }
}

ADUserInformation *user = cacheItem.userInformation;

if(user == nil) return false;

if([cacheItem isExpired]){
    return [self refreshToken:resourceId completionHandler:completionBlock];
}
else
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:user.userId forKey:@"LogInUser"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    completionBlock(cacheItem.accessToken);

    return true;
}
}
```

Using this code and Office 365 SDK in place you can get the outlook events for a particular user, before that make sure you have full permissions in the Azure AD else you may get 0 events as response.

Please note all the methods are from the SDK example apart from the first method to view how to fetch the events i would recommend to download the [exchange example from the github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-iOS/tree/master/Samples/simple-exchange-app).

Comment: I have no idea for the down vote as the code sample from office 365 has entire details for the same. If i could get a little help via comments to improve the answer please let me know

Comment: SO likes to avoid answers that depend upon links. A quote of the relevant segment of the official docs (alongside the link) means the answer remains helpful if the remote site is unavailable.

Comment: @Sobrique : alright let me add more data in my answer thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MSGraph SDK to fetch calendars and events:

Check this link: Configuration process is same, only fetching events is different(**see given code for fetching events**):

[How to Fetch/Create calender by O365-iOS-Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191962/how-to-fetch-create-calender-by-o365-ios-connect/41409613#41409613)

**Note**: Above link is used to fetch calendars from outlook the process is same for this but you should use this code after authentication and completed get events action look like this:

```
    - (IBAction)getCalendarsEvents:(id)sender {


[NXOAuth2AuthenticationProvider setClientId:clientId
                                     scopes:@[@"https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite",
                                              @"https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite"]];
[[NXOAuth2AuthenticationProvider sharedAuthProvider] loginWithViewController:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [MSGraphClient setAuthenticationProvider:[NXOAuth2AuthenticationProvider sharedAuthProvider]];
        self.client = [MSGraphClient client];

        // Authentication done

        [[[[_client me] events] request] getWithCompletion:^(MSCollection *response, MSGraphUserEventsCollectionRequest *nextRequest, NSError *error){

            NSArray *arr = response.value;
            MSGraphEvent *event = arr.firstObject;

            // Here you will getting outlook events

        }];

    }
}];

    }
```