# Unable to authenticate user via iOS Outlook SDK

Tags: ios, outlook, outlook-restapi

I'm trying with iOS Outlook SDK introduced at dev.outlook.com, their source code at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-iOS

I tried to register an application via Application registration tool with both an Office365 developer account and Outlook development account(request from Outlook) to get clientId, but none of them is working, I try to authenticate user but get error Application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' is not supported for this API version

Could anyone let me know how to get a valid clientId to work with this SDK?

Comment: Check this link. If you found some help in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191962/how-to-fetch-create-calender-by-o365-ios-connect/41409613#41409613

Answer (score 0):

That sample requires the use of the Azure v1 app model, which requires that you register the app in Azure AD, per these instructions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually.